# CUDA and if and else if

Tags: c, cuda

When a CUDA kernel contains conditional code like this:

```
if (statement1)
  calculation1;

else if (statement2)
  calculation2;

else if (statement3)
  calculation3;
```

does it means that calculations will be serialized?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Serialization of execution in CUDA happens whenever there is divergent branching within a single warp of threads. So in your abstract example, if any of the three statements do not evaluate to be the same for any given *warp* then there will be branch divergence and instruction replay of some combination of the three calculation code blocks, producing serialization *for that warp*. But if the conditions evaluate to be the same at the warp level, then there is no serialization.

You should also keep in mind that there is conditional execution in CUDA, so if you had something like this:

```
if (statement1) 
  calculation1; 
end if
```

even if `statement1` was not true for all threads in a warp, there will not be any serialization, instead some of the threads in the warp just perform the equivalent of a `NOOP`.

So there is no general answer to your question - depending on the structure of the code, the input data which determines the conditions, and the grouping of the evaluation of the conditions between warps, there may or may not be serialization. In general, the architecture and compiler is much more tolerant of branching than many people imagine, and sensibly written code containing branches and conditions will pay only a small (or even negligible) performance penalty. The CUDA profiler provides quite a lot of information about serialization and instruction replay -- that should be your main guide for understanding the effect of branching on the performance of a given piece of code.